# Winforms Individually Format Double Values in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to individually format items in a combo box in C#/Winforms. The combo box contains a set of doubles taken from a set of objects assigned to it (e.g., 1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03 etc.)

What I need to do is format them so that the read (1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03 etc.) **not** (1.00, 1.01, 1.02 etc.)

I know that the format string property can be used to format the whole collection, but is there a way to do some form of conditional formatting on the item collection by crating a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format each item individually by supplying a handler for the [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format.aspx) event.

The event handler looks like this:

```
private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
```

You can then modify `e.Value` as you so wish.

Comment: how can I then change how the e.Value format is changed, by using a call to String.Format?

Comment: Change it however you like. `String.Format` is the obvious choice.

Comment: You will need more than String.Format.  You'll have to write a custom function to handle the special case of 1.0

Comment: @Steve and presumably 2.0, 3.0 etc.

Comment: Correct, just writing a function to return the appropriately formatted number now