# Winforms ComboBox ICustomFormatter

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've been trying to use an `ICustomFormatter` with a `ComboBox`'s `FormatInfo` property. I can get my formatter to perform correctly if I use it with `String.Format(...)`. I can also get it to perform correctly with the `ComboBox`, but only if I populate the `ComboBox` with custom objects. What I would really like is for the `ComboBox` to use my formatter for *every* type that populates the `ComboBox`. If I populate the `ComboBox` with doubles, the `formatType` argument for the `GetFormat(...)` method of my `IFormatProvider` is `NumberFormatInfo` rather than `ICustomFormatter`.

Is there a way to allow my formatter to be used for *any* type that populates the `ComboBox`?

### Example Code

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 0, new A(1), new B(2), new C(3) });

        var formatter = new CustomFormatter();

        comboBox1.FormatInfo = formatter;
        comboBox1.FormatString = "0";

        // This prints 4ft in the Output window
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(formatter, "{0}", 4));

        // The comboBox's drop down will show the following:
        // 0 <= **This is the one I'm interested in. can I force usage of my CustomFormatter for int/float/double/etc.**
        // CustomFormatterTest.A
        // 2
        // 3ft
    }
}

public class CustomFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        // A breakpoint placed here will get hit 4 times
        // 1: formatType is NumberFormatInfo
        // 2. formatType is ICustomFormatter
        // 2.5. this object's Format method gets called
        // 3. formatType is ICustomFormatter
        // 3.5. this object's Format method gets called
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

    // 2.5. arg is 3
    // 3.5. arg is 4
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}ft", (int)arg);
    }
}

public class A
{
    private int _i;

    public A(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }
}

public class B
{
    private int _i;

    public B(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _i.ToString();
    }
}

public class C : IFormattable
{
    private int _i;

    public E(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var formatter = formatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(ICustFormatter)) as ICustomFormatter;

        if (formatter != null)
        {
            return formatter.Format(format, _i, formatProvider);
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

So, what I'm interested in is the `0` here:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 0, new A(1), new B(2), new C(3) });
```

**Is there a way to apply the formatting provided by my custom formatter to that `0` without wrapping it in a separate object?**

Comment: can you show your code perhaps you are doing something wrong or incorrectly. thanks is this link helpful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014878/how-to-use-numberformatinfo-to-remove-parenthesis-for-negative-values

Comment: @DJKRAZE added an example and clarified.

Comment: What about using the format event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567198/winforms-individually-format-double-values-in-combobox

Comment: @Loathing that was what I ended up doing to solve my immediate problem, but it would still be nice to know why the original problem occurs.